# Taylor series expansion of a function which is undefined at a point

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have a function $f(x)$ which is well defined and differentiable in the whole $\mathbb{R^+}$, positive section of real line, except it is undefined at the origin $x=0$. I want to show that near the $x=0$ the function in negative. I was able to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 0$ and also $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x) < 0$. Now I want to use these two facts to show $f(x)\le 0$ near origin.

I think I can't use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $x=0$ and $x=\epsilon$ to get the result (because function is undefined at $x=0$), however can it be used in the limit of $x\to 0^+$ like the following

$$f'(0^+) = \frac{f(\epsilon) - \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)}{\epsilon - 0} \le 0 \overset{\mathrm{\epsilon >0}}{\Rightarrow} f(\epsilon)\le 0 $$

Am I wrong?

My question: is there a theorem that guarantees $f(x) \le 0$ when $x\in (0,\epsilon)$ is in a small neighborhood of origin (for some small positive $\epsilon$) even though the function and its derivatives are not defined at $x=0$ (for example a modified version of mean value theorem)?

================================EDIT===============================

What if I define $f_2(x) = \begin{cases}f(x), &x > 0\\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$

Now the function is continuous and right differentiable.

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$ you can say nothing based on the above.

Comment: @copper.hat, thank you for the comment. What about the answer provided by geetha290krm below? Is it wrong? Also I want to emphasize that I calculated $f'(x)$ using derivation formulas, and to be sure, you mean there is no way to analytically decide about the sign of $f(x)$ around origin?! Thank you.

Comment: Ignore my comment, I thought you were trying to show $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $f'(x) <0$ for all $x \in (0,\epsilon)$. So $f$ is decreasing in this interval. If $f(x) >0$ for some $x$ in this interval we can choose $y$ close enough to $0$ so that $y<x$ and $f(y) <f(x)$  (because $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 0$) but this contradicts the fact that $f$ is decreasing.